# bibliography includes the items that were not cited

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I'm using the mcbibliography to create the reference list. I have commented some references in my text but the items did not disappeared from the bibliography. What can be done? This is a part of my bibliography:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\RequirePackage{mcite}
\RequirePackage{cite}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
{ abstract}
\end{abstract}

\clearpage
\section{Introduction}
intro
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%       Bibliography
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\providecommand{\etal}{et al.\xspace}
\providecommand{\coll}{Collaboration}
\catcode`\@=11
\def\@bibitem#1{%
\ifmc@bstsupport
  \mc@iftail{#1}%
    {;\newline\ignorespaces}%
    {\ifmc@first\else.\fi\orig@bibitem{#1}}
  \mc@firstfalse
\else
  \mc@iftail{#1}%
    {\ignorespaces}%
    {\orig@bibitem{#1}}%
\fi}%
\catcode`\@=12
\begin{mcbibliography}{10}
\bibitem{zfp:c13:207}
first ,
\newblock 123456\relax
\relax
\bibitem{zfp:c38:371}
second \coll, 
\newblock56781\relax
\relax
\end{mcbibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @seamus, thank you for the advice, this is done

Comment: If you are creating the bibliography manually, you have to remove or comment the items you don't want to appear. It is not enough to remove the citations from the text. (If you were using BibTeX or Biblatex, things are different. But you're not doing that.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with mcbibliography package, but any time I used this type of commands for the references:

```
 \bibitem{zfp:c13:207}
    first ,
    \newblock 123456\
```

regardless of the package, I had the same output as you mentioned. It means that I'll care myself about the references. These commands, `\bibitem` are supposed to be in BBL files. So, `\cite` command will only refer to the item.

As far as I got from the manual page of this package, it also depends on the Bibtex tool. I assume that you are doing this to use a grouped citation. I tried it on some Tex files of my own papers and it worked for me. So, don't add the references by `\bibitem` if you want Bibtex to manage them (and you want!). Use the normal way. I mean gathering the references in a file and calling the file by the commands

```
\bibliographystyle{your bib style file}
\bibliography{your bib file}
```

If you are not familiar with these commands, here is a short instruction: https://www.economics.utoronto.ca/osborne/latex/BIBTEX.HTM.

Then, anywhere in the text, you can refer to a group of the references by `\mcite{label}`.